# How to update spring cache when using spring data repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, jms, spring-cache

I am trying to implement a replicated cache in a spring managed distributed application using activemq (jms). Multiple instances of the application server should update their copy of the cache when one of them triggers a change. I am trying to implement a standalone application to mimic this.

I have a spring boot rest application that uses spring data's CrudRepository. I have enabled caching by adding the @Cacheable annotations.

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person,Long>{

    @Cacheable(value="myCache")
    List<Person> findAll();

    @Override
    @CacheEvict(value="myCache", allEntries=true)
    Person save(Person p);

}
```

How can I update this cache that is managed by spring through some custom code? There are two events when update is required

1. When the save method is called I would like to execute the jms producer code to push the java object (Person) on a jms topic. How can I add custom behavior to call the jms producer code after saving the java object in the save method?
2. Update the cache (myCache) in the jms consumer code. How can I get a handle to this cache in the spring data repository external to this interface in order to so?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `@Cacheable` for that. Instead use the proper caching integration for your persistence provider (probably hibernate). Also why implement your own caching, there are several proven solutions out there.

Comment: We are building our own caching framework to have fine grained control over it. We have tried some of the popular ones like JBoss TreeCache but they have proven to be a failure for us.

Even if use a different caching integration how do I intercept spring data repository calls?

Comment: You shouldn't. You should integrate with your persistence provider. Calling save isn't mandatory, what if someone uses a `@Modifying` annotation on a `@Query` to define an update. You can try and tell everyone to also put `@CacheEvict` etc. on it but it will fail. You need better integration. So if you want anything you need to implement your caching on the level of the persistence provider and not using Springs caching abstraction. For that implement the proper interfaces and configure the provider accordingly.

Comment: @M.Deinum But what happens if you want multiple keys and not just the @Id ? For example, `@Cacheable(key = "#name") Optional<Obj> findByName(String name);`

Comment: Use the query cache and the second level caching is actually pretty smart on to check if something is already cached based on the actual result/id of the entity.